# Getting a directory of a tasks file for relative paths

Tags: ansible

In my playbook I run a local_action that executes a script and stores the value for future use:

```
- local_action: command python release.py
  register: release_url
```

This worked great, until I moved my playbook into a subdirectory. It turns out that the command runs from your current working directory (that you run ansible from), so the path needs to look like this:

```
- local_action: command python roles/ghost/release.py
```

I have a directory structure as below:

- group_vars/
- roles/

  - ghost/

    - tasks/

      - main.yml
    - templates/
    - release.py
- site.yml

However the roles/**ghost** folder name can change (and hard-coding this won't let you run the playbook from another directory).

How can I get the directory path of tasks/main.yml (which issues the local_action command), so I can give a relative path to it?

Answer (score 6):

[As of ansible 1.8, there's a `role_path` variable defined](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/7051cdeb57d947a213803ca28a4e1a6a2f905d26) that you can use for this purpose.

Comment: `The error was: 'role_path' is undefined`
It seems this can only be used in roles, not commands

Answer (score 2):

Can you put release.py script in roles/ghost/files/ and then use it with local_action

```
- name: local scrpt 
  local_action: script release.py
```

And that way you may not need to get the directory path

This makes reference to doing so in the Directory Layout part http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/playbooks_best_practices.html

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/rmasters/ghost-ansible/pull/4) before I saw this SO question, but here's the gist of it.

1. Move the script to a 'files' directory within the role
2. Since we can't know which path the script will be in, copy it to /tmp:

   ```
   - name: copy ghost release script to tmp
     local_action: copy src=release.py dest=/tmp/release.py
     sudo: no
   ```
3. Then we can run the script

   ```
   - name: get ghost release version
     local_action: command python /tmp/release.py
     register: ghost_release
     sudo: no
   ```

We choose `sudo: no` in case the outer playbook sets it globally to `on`. We don't need root for this action, and it can break the ansible run if it needs to ask for a password.

There may also be a better way to do step 2, by randomising the file name somehow by using a fact, then removing the file in an extra step after we've run the script. This can minimise the risk involved in there potentially being a file called `/tmp/release.py` already.